# Cannot change Button.Content in XAML

Tags: wpf, triggers

I want to change content of a Button in XAML using a DataTrigger. Conditionally I need to change the text of the button. However, if the Button initially have a text, the text is not changed. The only way to make it work is either not to set `Content`, or set it with a Trigger.

So if I have

```
<Button Content="Some text" />
```

the trigger doesn't change the button text.

If I have

`<Button />`

or

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Some text" />
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

the trigger works.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of DepedencyProperty precedence. see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx

Local values have a higher precedence order than triggers. This means the local value will "take precedence" over the trigger value

When you set it in the Style it changes the precedence. A Trigger takes precedence over a Style Setter and this is why it works as you expect.

Comment: So, should I always set the initial text with a trigger if I want to change it later, or is there another (better) way to change the text of the Button after I set it with a local value?

Comment: Changing text in a trigger is a little odd in general, but if you must do it then I like to create a re-usable style for it. Then set the default text in a style setter and have the style contain the trigger that modifies the text. This makes it clear what is happening imo.

Comment: I set the button text depending on the state of the object, being edited in a dialog, if the object is not suspended, the button writes "Suspend", if suspended - writes "Resume" - I use a style with a trigger in XAML as I believe this is a View's responsibility to set the button's text.

Comment: You could also just bind the Button Content to the Suspended property and then Write an IValueConverter that converts the suspended property value in to the correct button content value. This is pretty much what  converters are for.